# Restrict email attachment access

Tags: security, email

I'm in a situation where I need to force the recipients of email attachments to accept an agreement before being able to download/read the attachment.

So ideally, I would send an email, and then the recipient would click on a link (or whatever) and be forced to click "I Agree" to some terms before they were allowed to access the attachment.  Ideally, we would log their name (or other identifying information) with their acceptance, so we would have a record of it.

Does anyone know about any solutions that are similar to this?  I also considered some kind of encrypted archive with terms acceptance, or something like that.  Primarily, these will be PDF attachments, so if there is something within Acrobat we can do, that works as well.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People won't/shouldn't/can't open attachments with any of functionality to implement this sort of thing.

Your best bet might be to link to a website where they can agree and then download the file.

Comment: Does anyone know of any sites that offer such a service?